# How can I create a List with predefined Id in SharePoint Apps?

Tags: list, 2013, sharepoint-addin

I'm working on the Apps development for SharePoint 2013. I need a List for my app, so I can do it using visual studio. But I can't find any option to set up an Id for my List. Is it possible?

P.S. I can get my List by title, but I want to get it by Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It isn't possible if the list is in the app package because the ID is
>   generated during publishing.

So, the only way is to first get the list by title and then get the ID of this list.

Otherwise, I don't think you can get the ID without first getting the list by title because the ID is generated when your app containing the list is published.

Comment: He does not want to get the ID of a list, he want's to create the list with a specific ID

Comment: That's why I said that it isn't possible if the list is in the app package because the ID is generated during publishing :)

Comment: No you just changed your answer, but thats ok, now it is more descriptive ;)

Comment: Yes I've added "I think the only way is to " in the beginning of my post :) it is more descriptive indeed.